# Troubles with AVRO schema update

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, akka-stream, akka-kafka, avro4s

I have a simple case class:

```
  case class User(id: String, login: String, key: String)
```

i am add field "name"

```
  case class User(id: String, login: String, name: String, key: String)
```

then add this field in avro schema (user.avsc)

```
{
  "namespace": "test",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "User",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "id", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "login", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "name", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "key", "type": "string" }
  ]
}
```

this class is used other case class:

```
case class AuthRequest(user: User, session: String)
```

chema (auth_request.avsc)

```
{
  "namespace": "test",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "AuthRequest",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "user", "type": "User" },
    { "name": "session", "type": "string" }
  ]
}
```

after that change my consumer start throws exceptons

```
Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("token_service_auth_request"))
    .map { msg =>
      Try {
        val in: ByteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(msg.record.value())
        val input: AvroBinaryInputStream[AuthRequest] = AvroInputStream.binary[AuthRequest](in)
        val result: AuthRequest = input.iterator.toSeq.head !!!! here is exception
        msg.committableOffset.commitScaladsl()

        (msg.record.value(), result, msg.record.key())
      } match {
        case Success((a: Array[Byte], value: AuthRequest, key: String)) =>
          log.info(s"listener got $msg -> $a -> $value")

          context.parent ! value

        case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
      }
    }
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty stream    at
>   scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Empty$.head(Stream.scala:1104)  at
>   scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Empty$.head(Stream.scala:1102)  at
>   test.consumers.AuthRequestListener.$anonfun$new$2(AuthRequestListener.scala:39)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)     at
>   test.consumers.AuthRequestListener.$anonfun$new$1(AuthRequestListener.scala:36)
>     at
>   test.consumers.AuthRequestListener.$anonfun$new$1$adapted(AuthRequestListener.scala:35)
>     at akka.stream.impl.fusing.Map$$anon$9.onPush(Ops.scala:51)     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:519)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:482)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:378)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:588)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:472)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:563)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:745)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:760)
>     at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)  at
>   akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)  at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:670)
>     at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:588)     at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)  at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)   at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)  at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)     at
>   akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)     at
>   akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

I tried to clean builds and invalidate cache - i seems like some kind of caching previous version of schema in some there
Help please!

Comment: Your change to the User class is a non backwards compatible Avro modification. You added a field without making it nullable or have a default for previous Avro records trying to use the Schema they were sent with. Not sure if that's related to your error

Comment: Thanks! You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your change backward compatible making the new field nullable and adding a default value to it.

```
{
  "namespace": "test",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "User",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "id", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "login", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "name", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null },
    { "name": "key", "type": "string" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped :)
and I'm seriously starting to think about using schema registry :)